# Div collision after floating

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have some divs and I want to do them the following way
parent div (topDiv) holds three divs
they float (Left, left, right). topDiv does not float.

After this topDiv I have bottomDiv. This div does not float either.
The problem is that topDiv and bottomDiv collides into each.

I want to do like this:

```
DIV1 DIV2 DIV3<br>
DIV1 <br>
DIV4
```

But I get

```
DIV1 DIV2 DIV3 **DIV4**
<br>DIV1
```

Here is code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topDiv" >
        <div id = "t1" style="float:left;"> 
            DIV1 <br> DIV1 next line
        </div>
        <div id = "t2" style="float:left;"> DIV2 </div>
        <div id = "t3" style="float:left;"> DIV3 </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "bottomDiv" style=" background-color:red;"> 
        DIV4 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfloated items don't 'contain' floats in a layout. Set both `topDiv` and `bottomDiv` to `overflow:hidden` to contain the floats.

There are other ways of containing floats. In addition to `overflow: hidden` the is the [micro clearfix method](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) as well as simply floating the parent container (give it a width of 100%). Even more in this article [Simple Tips on Containing Floats](http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/containing-floats).

Different methods have different drawbacks so pick the method that works best for your layout. For instance, `overflow:hidden` is a solid way to go... unless you have a flyout menu or something that shouldn't be hidden!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not clearing your floats.  You want to do

```
<div id="topDiv" >
    <div id = "t1" style="float:left;"> 
        DIV1 <br> DIV1 next line
    </div>
    <div id = "t2" style="float:left;"> DIV2 </div>
    <div id = "t3" style="float:left;"> DIV3 </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id = "bottomDiv" style="clear: both; background-color:red;"> 
    DIV4 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'topDiv' div doesn't have a height, hence your 'bottomDiv' appears at the top of the page. To prevent this we have to add the 'overflow: hidden;' rule to our 'topDiv', to do that we add this code:

```
<div id="topDiv" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

Here's a JSFiddle with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6wyw/

Answer (score 1):

Try using a "clear" div after your floats. It will reset the floats and reduce some conflicts.

At the end of your code, before the last  add the following

```
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <style>
    .clear {
            clear: both;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topDiv" >
        <div id = "t1" style="float:left;"> 
            DIV1 <br> DIV1 next line
        </div>
        <div id = "t2" style="float:left;"> DIV2 </div>
        <div id = "t3" style="float:left;"> DIV3 </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id = "bottomDiv" style=" background-color:red;"> 
        DIV4 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if is this what you are asking for but you can check try this

```
<div id="topDiv" >
    <div id="left-container" style="float:left">
        <div id = "t1" style="float:left;"> DIV1 </div> 
        <div id = "t2" style="float:left;"> DIV2 </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-container" style="float:right">
        <div id = "t3"> DIV3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</br>
<div id = "bottomDiv" style=" background-color:red;"> 
    DIV4 
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3tN5/)